# Django - Allauth - How to add additional API parameters to registration

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I'm using Django [all-auth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) through Django [rest-auth](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth) and I'd like to extend the registration functionality to match my custom user object. Given the user model below:

```
class Profile(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, blank=True)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
```

How can I enable allauth to receive those as parameters via an API call to then clean/store them. In other words, what I want to be able to do, is call the `/rest-auth/registration/` endpoint with a body like such;

```
{
  "username": "foo",
  "email": "bar@mail.com",
  "password1": "fooBar!@",
  "password2": "fooBar!@",
  "first_name": "first",
  "last_name": "last"
}
```

and have `first_name` and `last_name` stored as a Profile object. Again, I want to be able to do this via the API and not via a form.

---

Environment details:

```
Django==1.11.3
django-allauth==0.33.0
django-environ==0.4.4
django-rest-auth==0.9.1
django-storages==1.6.5
django-taggit==0.22.1
djangorestframework==3.6.4
...

$ python --version
Python 2.7.11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try overriding your registration serializer like this:

```
class CustomRegisterSerializer(RegisterSerializer):
    first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)

    def get_cleaned_data(self):
        validated_data = super(CustomRegisterSerializer, self).get_cleaned_data()
        validated_data.update({
            'first_name': self.validated_data.get('first_name', ''),
            'last_name': self.validated_data.get('last_name', '')
        })
        return validated_data
```

Then add this serializer into your settings as `REGISTER_SERIALIZER` (check docs for details)

Comment: Tried this, but the validated_data doesn't include any of the new parameters in validated_data.

Comment: sorry I used the wrong method, should be `update` instead of `extend`. Can you try again please?